# VS Code debugger can't find cwd path

Tags: c, debugging, vscode-debugger

Cannot debug C files in VS Code due to error "Unnable to start debuggin. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment-cd "D:\Documents\Faculdade\Periodo 2023.1\LLPI\C"". D:/Documents/Faculdade/Periodo 2023.1/LLPI/C: No such file or directory". I've tried a lot of things and still didn't get to make it work.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DndMR.png)

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build"
        },
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe Compilar e depurar o arquivo ativo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar a reformatação automática para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Definir Tipo de Desmontagem como Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "isDefault": true,
                "kind": "build"
            },
            "detail": "compilador: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                ""
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Tarefa gerada pelo Depurador."
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried renaming things, used a lot of different launch.json and taks.json codes i've found. Unninstalled and reinstalle VSCode and MinGW. Tried putting the path directally and nothing worked.